# TypeScript generic type parameters are inferred with functions, but not type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider this:

```
type SpecificKeys<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]: string;
};

const foobar: SpecificKeys<"foo" | "bar"> = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
};
```

I have to specify the union of the keys as the generic type argument when creating `foobar`, which is redundant. I can't figure any way around this. But if I write a do-nothing function:

```
function makeSpecificKeys<T extends string>(thing: SpecificKeys<T>): SpecificKeys<T> {
  return thing;
}

const foobarInferred = makeSpecificKeys({
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
});
```

then const `foobarInferred` is correctly typed as `SpecificKeys<"foo" | "bar">` and I didn't have to repeat myself by enumerating all the keys.

Is there any way to achieve inference of a generic type parameter when creating a typed variable without having to make a do-nothing function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is no. Type restricts the value, saying `a:T` means value `a` needs to be a member of type `T`, if not - then compile error. What you want is to say `a: infer me typeof a`, so in other way round.

Type annotations is for restricting the value, not value to restrict the type. **TS allows for taking type from the value, but it not allows for taking the type of the value and restricting it at once.**

---

Still, we can make some tricks to make it working. Consider type level solution:

```
type SpecificKeys<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]: string;
};

// type level version of makeSpecificKeys
type MakeSpecificKeys<T extends SpecificKeys<string>> = T;

const foobar = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar",
};
type FoobarType = MakeSpecificKeys<typeof foobar> // fine 

const badfoobar = {
  foo: 1, // number value dont match SpecificKeys
  bar: "bar",
};
type BadFoobarType = MakeSpecificKeys<typeof badfoobar> // error
```

[The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAZo+BpCIDOAeAKlBAB7AQB2AJtlNsAE6LkDmAfFALxQDeAsAFBQoAbQDWWKEyj4AugC5aDJswDcAgL5r+A0JCgBZAIbi4EJKgxY8hEmSo1T5tJhy46jFq3Zd8WgfAB7cjooZACAgCNDek4eASEwgIUAIkTkgBp4qCj6FJyMjS1daAAxcJz8cGguIxMEFGcrXGKA5FDy6PYAei7QpmhAXg3AGR2BfyCQqMpEnNi+QXakqABGdKgeqHIAVwBbCIgYgDdDABtN6Eog4Chtw2B4AAtYeosXbCycvOiC-k0dKqgAEKGShlSLRSp6GrGCCOBqWVwtNqTaadNa9fb0AIxYajbT8IA)

Both values `foobar` and `badfoobar` are inferred by TS properly without any type annotations. The next thing is calling type level `MakeSpecificKeys` which is kinda id function you have made before, but this one is at the type level, it restricts the argument type in the same way `makeSpecificKeys` was doing it. For the `badfoobar` it shows compile error.

What I have shown here is undoubtedly worst approach then value constructor `makeSpecificKeys` you have made. So stick to that. The one single point of using above approach is that nothing from it goes to the runtime, when `makeSpecificKeys` does.

Comment: I've played around with this sort of construct. The use case is that I am providing a type for third party consumers to use to construct valid JS object as input to a system. Other types they also will consume are derived from it. It seems somewhat backwards to provide guidance to them to create untyped objects first and then "see if they work" by using `typeof foobar`.  I also don't want them to have to use types that require duplication of all the keys as part of the typedef. Maybe just providing the passthrough function is the simplest solution for this situation as far as guiding users

Comment: Really i just want to be able to provide the simplest guidance on how to use my types to people who may be less advanced TS programmers, so it's mostly about what's the best looking example. But seems like these are all the options, thanks for clarifying what's possible.